# How to split the combined graph into a single graph separated in openpyxl

Tags: python, graph, openpyxl

Required to display the graph plotted by taking each row in X-Axis over a column set as Y-Axis. Here is my data imported from an Excel sheet and displayed into a separate Excel sheet.

[image]

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    Reference,
    BarChart3D
)

wb = Workbook()
fileItemPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Data.xlsx")
print('Input_FilePath: {}'.format(fileItemPath))
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileItemPath)
sheet = wb['TMO_Reliability_Stats_Combined']

# This part of the code assigning to data causing the whole trouble...
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=6)

titles = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=1)
chart = BarChart3D()
chart.title = "3D Bar Chart"
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
chart.set_categories(titles)
sheet.add_chart(chart, "A10")
wb.save("bar3d.xlsx")
```

In the above code, I am not able to assign the correct values
`data = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=6)`

**Actual Result:** Displaying combined graph instead of single.

**Expected Result:** Single graph needs to be plotted separately. The combined needs to be eliminated as shown in the snapshot

[image]

Comment: The code as is cannot lead to the result because the cells for 2021 are not included.

Comment: The code for displaying 2021 is not there in the above snippet. I just wanted to display only graph i.e for 2020 following the same I will cope up to display for 2021. But here the problem is for 2020 as it is displaying combined.. How should I able to approach this..? @CharlieClark

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you don't include the relevant code then we can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: @CharlieClark running the provided code does give the result shown

Comment: Yes @jezza_99 ..! Running the above code gives this exact same result as shown in the snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain of exactly why you are getting this error, but I believe it has to do with you using the openpyxl bar chart in a way it wasn't quite intended. It could just as easily something to do with Excel. Deep diving into the openpyxl source code for this module hasn't given me an answer yet.

However, altering your `data` to include the first column does solve your issue. The only way I could get a seperate graph for `2021` was to move the data and use cases so they were a seperate pair. While this isn't an ideal solution if you have many years, it does work as you intended.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    Reference,
    BarChart3D
)
import os
import openpyxl

wb = Workbook()
fileItemPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Data.xlsx")
print('Input_FilePath: {}'.format(fileItemPath))
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileItemPath)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

# Copying/moving 2021 data
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=5):
    # Copy data
    colA = row[0].value
    colC = row[2].value

    # Delete colC
    row[2].value = None

    # Paste data
    row[3].value = colA
    row[4].value = colC

# 2020 chart
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=6)
titles = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1)
chart = BarChart3D()
chart.title = "3D Bar Chart"
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
chart.set_categories(titles)
sheet.add_chart(chart, "A10")

# 2021 chart
data = Reference(sheet, min_col=4, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=6)
titles = Reference(sheet, min_col=5, min_row=1)
chart = BarChart3D()
chart.title = "3D Bar Chart"
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
chart.set_categories(titles)
sheet.add_chart(chart, "J10")

# Saving
wb.save("bar3d.xlsx")
```

Outputted bar charts:
[image: bar charts]

Comment: Hi, @jezza_99 could fine-tune my posted code to be more generic and precise with the Y-Axis scale to be percentage-wise. As I am getting the expected result for additional data given in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl.chart import (
    Reference,
    BarChart3D
)
from openpyxl.styles.numbers import FORMAT_PERCENTAGE

fileItemPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Data.xlsx")

def movCopyCell(sheet):
    for (index, row) in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=8)):
        # Copy data
        colA = row[0].value
        colC = row[2].value
        colD = row[0].value
        colE = row[3].value

        # Delete 
        row[2].value = None
        row[3].value = None

        # Paste data
        row[3].value = colA
        # row[3].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
        row[4].value = colC
        # row[4].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
        row[6].value = colD
        # row[6].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
        row[7].value = colE
        # row[7].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE

def initalizeChartDetails(i, sheet):
    data = Reference(sheet, min_col=(1 + (i - 1) * 3), min_row=2, max_col=((i + 1) + (i - 1) * 2), max_row=6)
    titles = Reference(sheet, min_col=((i+1) + (i-1)*2), min_row=1)
    chart = BarChart3D()
    chart.title = "3D Bar Chart"
    chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
    chart.set_categories(titles)
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        columnName = chr(72) + f'{i * 20}'
    else:
        columnName = chr(65) + f'{i * 20}'
    sheet.add_chart(chart, columnName)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileItemPath)
sheet = wb['TMO_Reliability_Stats_Combined']
movCopyCell(sheet)
for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    initalizeChartDetails(i, sheet)
else:
    # save the file
    wb.save("bar3d.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi, @jezza_99 Could you make this code a little bit more generic. As I am getting the required output by additional column data with 2022 from excel. `movCopyCell()` needs to be fine-tuned with percentage data to be displayed and Column A, B,... till the end reaches from an Excel code should be generic. Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, are you not able to figure out how to iterate through the columns?